# EOFError by using joblib.load

Tags: python, pickle, joblib, eoferror

I try to load a umap_2.sav with the same environment with which I create the file but on another PC. I get an EOFError by using 50% of my memory.

```
umap_model_plot = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=15,
                               n_components=2,
                               metric='cosine', low_memory=True).fit(emb)

joblib.dump(umap_model_plot,'umap_2.sav')
```

On a other pc

```
umap_model_plot = joblib.load('umap_2.sav')
```

Error

```
umap_model_plot = joblib.load('umap_2.sav')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-f6a4b963c45a>", line 1, in <module>
    umap_model_plot = joblib.load('umap_2.sav')

  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\top2vec_final_\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)

  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\top2vec_final_\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()

  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\top2vec_final_\lib\pickle.py", line 1086, in load
    raise EOFError

EOFError
```

Comment: It looks like the file is corrupted or in a different format than the one expected. Unfortunately, without the file, it is impossible to reproduce the error. It could also be that you are using different pickle protocols. Are you sure the two computers have the same python and library version?

Comment: To be sure of the same versions I exported and imported the environment. Umap models a like scikit-learn models, could that be a problem?